How to perform a case-insensitive search based on a specific field value in Firestore?
I am trying to perform a query in Firestore where the field name and value should be matched irrespective of the case.
For example:
fruit = manGo , value = mango
code which considers case :
 const q = query(collection(db, 'CollectionName'), where(fruit, '==', value));

How can I perform case-insensitive queries in Firestore, and are there alternative solutions or best practices beyond storing and querying a lowercase version of the field?

There is no built-in case insensitive search in Firestore. See the link for built-in options, or consider using a third-party solution for text search: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search.
